# Solr best match not working in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch, solr, integration

I have used solr search in **Magento** but not find how to add specific attributes in search by **Best Match**.

I have tried to give it with bellow code in `Solr\Block\Catalogsearch\Autocomplete.php` in `SEARCH_TYPE_STRING_COMPLETION` but it is not working.

It works on if I search like `"testsku"` best match product should be first. If I search with `"custom product"` than best match of both word should be come first.

I have tried to find out solution but didn't found any.

Also I have shown that if I search with "customize" than Irrelevant product comes.

**Need for specific attributes only.**

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Magento 1.9 (CE) does not have built-in Solr support. Which extension are you using?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium extesion.